# Can a Deja Dup backup from Ubuntu be restored on Windows?

Tags: windows, backup, restore, deja-dup, media

My laptop got broken recently (I had Ubuntu on it), and I've backups of my files on external HDD. The problem is that my new laptop has Windows 8 on it and I don't feel like switching to Ubuntu on it just yet. Is there a way to restore my precious audio and video files to my new computer (all backup files are on GPG-format)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Déjà-Dup is a graphical front-end to [Duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) [(Wikipedia page)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicity_%28software%29), a command-line backup program. You can run Duplicity on Windows using Cygwin, and restore the files from the command line.

Setting up Duplicity on Windows may be somewhat involved. [This guy has some instructions](http://www.alexdimarco.ca/blog/15-duplicity-on-windows.html); you may be able to skip setting up some of the dependencies (pexpect, SSH) which are needed for making remote backups.

If I recall correctly, the command to restore is

```
duplicity restore file:///path/to/backup /path/to/restore/to
```

You can then access the restored files in that directory.

If you're not familiar with the command line, it would be easier to boot the computer off a live CD, and use `duplicity` or Déjà-Dup from Linux to restore the files onto your Windows partition.

Comment: [Here's an archive of that blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160302110622/http://www.alexdimarco.ca/blog/15-duplicity-on-windows.html)