# Restoring Ubuntu Files to Windows 11

Tags: backup

Got a new laptop for school, decided to try and learn to use Linux. That was all fun and good before I realized that it would be difficult to use for university for me. So, I backed up my files both on an external hard drive and on google drive, and booted up windows 11 for the first time. Now I'm struggling to get the files I had (which are in duplicity format) onto Windows 11 to complete the switch.
Thanks!

Comment: So you're asking [Can a Deja Dup backup from Ubuntu be restored on Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343058/can-a-deja-dup-backup-from-ubuntu-be-restored-on-windows)

Comment: I absolutely am, thanks!

Comment: ... note however that the accepted answer pre-dates WSL - you may find that WSL now provides a simpler route than Cygwin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read ext4 partitions in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows)